# VBA Vlookup Runtime error when pasting or deleting

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

Everything seems to work great until you try to delete more than one cell in the column OR past into more than one cell at the same time. Either of these actions cause the same runtime error and refer to the vlookup line in vba.

There are 2 different columns on this main page and if you try these actions on either column, you get the same error. I have referred to the other links about runtime 1004, and that is not the same issue as I have occurring here.

```
selectedNa = Target.Value
If Target.Column = 8 Then
    selectedNum = Application.VLookup(selectedNa, Worksheets("OPP Codes").Range("opp_code"), 2, False)

    If Not IsError(selectedNum) Then
        Target.Value = selectedNum
    End If
End If

selectedNa = Target.Value

If Target.Column = 7 Then
    selectedNum = Application.VLookup(selectedNa, Worksheets("OPP Codes").Range("opp_service"), 2, False)

    If Not IsError(selectedNum) Then
        Target.Value = selectedNum
    End If
End If
```

I simply want to be able to past into multiple rows in the column, or delete multiple cells with out this error occurring.

Comment: `If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub` before the code above.

Comment: well that was too easy! but now i have a second script below this one that is being affected by that. I need for when a person pastes in multiple rows of column "L" for column "M" to accept that bulk past in column "L".. this new line stopped that from working.
```
    Dim L As Range, M As Range, Inte As Range, r As Range
    Set L = Range("L:L")
    Set Inte = Intersect(L, Target)
    If Inte Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In Inte
            r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Range("B4")

        Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: Then instead of exiting the sub put the code above in the if block Else.

Comment: It accepted the above code being changed to an if then else set up but it still is applying your if statement to my second macro for some reason

Answer (score 0):

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub before the code above. – Scott Craner